# Can we able to write the data into existing .csv file using wso2esb4.8.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb4.8.0.I wish to write the data into `.CSV` file using wso2esb4.8.0
if file is empty i am able to write means Append but my issue is already has file just i need to add one more data column to that
m csv file is

```
mdata
======
john,us,24,monnaco
ahemad,uk,54,bresbane
rajulak,srilanks,35,dar
```

above my csv file look like but i need to write(ADD) data in next column like this'
Desire .CSV file is

```
mdata
==========
john,us,24,monnaco,man
ahemad,uk,54,bresbane,man
rajulak,srilanks,35,dar,man
```

like this i wish to write the data into existing row only
how would i achive this
i tried this but its adding in next row
actually that one column may come from my client as json data
i wsih to add into that .CSV file
i have done like this but no use my config is

```
<inSequence>
    <log level="full"/>type="STRING"/>
    <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" expression="mdata.csv" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
    <send>
        <endpoint>
            <address uri="vfs:file:///Y6/Desktop/MyOutputDirectory?transport.vfs.Append=true"/>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
</inSequence>
```

how would i achive my desire file format is there any way into esb or not

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by writing your own class mediator to write to .csv file as your desired format. VFS does not support the requirement of writing custom files in different formats. You can write a simple java code to achieve this . Please refer [1] for more info how to write a custom mediatorfor WSO2 ESB.

[1]. http://wso2.com/library/2898/

Thank You,
Dharshana.